# How to create async fixture with yield that returns result

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest

I have this code:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
async def my_fixture():
    result = 5
    yield result
    print("Db connection closing or smth yet")


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_my_fixt(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture == 5
```

If I run this I will have

```
FAILED tests/t.py::test_my_fixt - assert <async_generator object my_fixture at 0x7fa13415c450> == 5
```

Is there anything I can do to make `my_fixture` return just `5`, not `AsyncGenerator`?

Comment: You need to install the pytest asyncio plugin. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73499640/3280538

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async fixtures with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936724/async-fixtures-with-pytest)

Comment: Had the same issue. `@pytest.mark.asyncio` didn't help but `asyncio_mode = "auto"` in `pyproject.toml` did (`trio_mode = "true"` too)

Comment: Did you try await myfixture == 5?